# How to get the 'access_token' in Facebook App for Unity3D

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine

Attempting to get the user's name via FB.API using C# in Unity3D:

```
        FB.API("/me/name", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, LogCallback);
```

This is giving me an error:

```
Without an access_token param explicitly passed in formData, some API graph calls will 404 error in the Unity Editor.
```

I don't know how to get the access token.. I've tried a lot of searching, copy/pasting various "solutions" but none of them working for me.  All I want is my "LogCallback" function to post a debug message with the user's name.

For example, I have this code, but it is setting a 'string' variable which is obviously not "WWWForm" data...

```
public static IEnumerator GetAppAccessToken() {
    //Debug.Log("asking FB for App AccessToken");
    string url = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_ id={0}&client_secret={1}",
                               "608042192582543",
                               "5021e9e8f246535e70effa5db4404170");

    WWW fbRequest = new WWW(url);

    // Wait for download to complete
    yield return fbRequest;

    string accessToken = fbRequest.text;
    //Debug.Log("got token: " + accessToken);
    accessToken = accessToken.Substring(accessToken.IndexOf("=") + 1);
    //Debug.Log("trimmed token: " + accessToken);

    FacebookAppAccessId = accessToken;

    return true;
}
```

So I don't really know what to do with that either or if it is even needed...  I think if I can just get the user's name (or better, a unique FB id), then I will be in business!

Comment: I wouldn't mind if someone could tell me how to get the user's name instead of the ID (for display purposes)... And/or their profile pic?

Comment: void OnLoggedIn() {
  FB.API("/me?fields=id,first_name,friends.limit(100).fields(first_name,id)", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, APICallback);
 }

 void APICallback(FBResult result) {
  if (result.Error != null) {
   FB.API("/me?fields=id,first_name,friends.limit(100).fields(first_name,id)", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, APICallback);
   return;
  }

  GameMainScript.instance.profile = Util.DeserializeJSONProfile(result.Text);
  FBName.text = "Welcome back, "+GameMainScript.instance.profile["first_name"];
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow...

```
FB.UserId
```

Problem solved!